# MySQL won't create my modeled database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, eer-model

I'm modeling my database with MySQL Wordbench in a EER Model, which is this :

[image: system]

So after modeling my database I export to a SQL script and try to run it, but it creates only three tables:

[image: tables]

Why is that happening ?
It shouldn't create all tables ?

This is the generated script when I export:

```
    SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `brainset` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci ;
USE `brainset` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`departamento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`departamento` (
  `ID` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `departamento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `departamento_UNIQUE` (`departamento` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`documento_escopo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`documento_escopo` (
  `ID` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `escopo` CHAR(7) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `escopo_UNIQUE` (`escopo` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`procedimento_tipo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`procedimento_tipo` (
  `ID` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `tipo_UNIQUE` (`tipo` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = '     ';


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`procedimento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`procedimento` (
  `ID` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `nome` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL ,
  `id_tipo` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_departamento` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_documento_complementar` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_procedimento-procedimento_tipo` (`id_tipo` ASC, `id_departamento` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_procedimento-departamento` (`id_departamento` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_procedimento-procedimento_tipo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo` , `id_departamento` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`procedimento_tipo` (`ID` , `ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_procedimento-departamento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_departamento` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`departamento` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`usuario` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `nome` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `foto` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `senha` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`documento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`documento` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `id_procedimento` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `data` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  `revisao` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `id_escopo` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_documento_complementar` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `id_usuario` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_documento-documento_escopo` (`id_escopo` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_documento-procedimento` (`id_procedimento` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_documento-documento` (`id_documento_complementar` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_documento-usuario` (`id_usuario` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_documento-documento_escopo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_escopo` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`documento_escopo` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_documento-procedimento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_procedimento` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`procedimento` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_documento-documento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_documento_complementar` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`documento` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_documento-usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`usuario` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`questao`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`questao` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `questao` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL ,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(1024) NULL ,
  `observacao` VARCHAR(1024) NULL ,
  `data` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`questao_tipo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`questao_tipo` (
  `ID` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`questao_campo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`questao_campo` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_questao` INT NOT NULL ,
  `id_questao_tipo` TINYINT NOT NULL ,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(1024) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_questao_campo-questao` (`id_questao` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_questao_campo-questao-tipo` (`id_questao_tipo` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_questao_campo-questao`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_questao` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`questao` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_questao_campo-questao-tipo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_questao_tipo` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`questao_tipo` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`questao_escolha`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`questao_escolha` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_questao_campo` INT NOT NULL ,
  `nome` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
  `valor` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_questao_escolha-questao_campo` (`id_questao_campo` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_questao_escolha-questao_campo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_questao_campo` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`questao_campo` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`questao_resposta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`questao_resposta` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_questao` INT NOT NULL ,
  `resposta` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL ,
  `data` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`questao_consulta`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`questao_consulta` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_usuario` INT NOT NULL ,
  `id_questao` INT NOT NULL ,
  `id_questao_resposta` INT NOT NULL ,
  `data` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_questao_consulta-usuario` (`id_usuario` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_questao_consulta-questao` (`id_questao` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_questao_consulta-questao_resposta` (`id_questao_resposta` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_questao_consulta-usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`usuario` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_questao_consulta-questao`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_questao` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`questao` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_questao_consulta-questao_resposta`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_questao_resposta` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`questao_resposta` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = '     ';


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `brainset`.`departamento_equipe`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `brainset`.`departamento_equipe` (
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_departamento` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `id_usuario` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_departamento_equipe-departamento` (`id_departamento` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_departamento_equipe-usuario` (`id_usuario` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_departamento_equipe-departamento`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_departamento` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`departamento` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_departamento_equipe-usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario` )
    REFERENCES `brainset`.`usuario` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Thanks.

Comment: does mysql output anything after you execute the code?

Comment: @Stu nope, it just says that complete the query with success

Comment: weird, can you paste the sql, or is it sensitive data?

Comment: @Stu I did now, is a simple system, no problem =]

Comment: I get the following error, after the first three tables are created; `MySQL said: 

#1005 - Can't create table 'brainset.procedimento' (errno: 150)`

Comment: looks like you're defining a relation before you've created the referencing tables, trying changing the order of the `create tables` statements so that any table that is referenced by another is created before the table that references it, if that makes sense? - in particular table  `departamento` needs to be created before `procedimento_tipo`

Comment: @Stu you're right, I'm gonna try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this; you can't create a table with a relation to a table that's not created yet.

When MySQL creates a relation it links the table you're creating the relation for to the table you're referencing, if the referencing table doesn't exist, MySQL won't be happy about it.

So when creating a lot of tables that reference each other, make sure that any table that is referenced by another is created before the table that references it.

Comment: +1 And if there are circular references (or just can't be bothered with the table creation order), create all the tables first, and use the `ALTER TABLE ... ADD FOREIGN KEY ...` afterwards.

Comment: good advice @Branko for people who have a massive number of tables!